# cannot convert int[] to int

Tags: java, arrays, int

```
public class NewChanceOefententamen {

    /* de methode die checkt of het getal voorkomt*/
    public static boolean komtVoorIn(int zoekgetal, int[] lijst){

        //voor elk getal in het array
        for (int i = 0; i < lijst.length; i++){

            //als het overeenkomt met de waarde in het array
            if (zoekgetal == lijst[i]){ 
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int[] zoekgetal = new int[3];
        int[] getal = new int[3];
        getal = new int [3];
        getal[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
        getal[1] = (int)(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
        getal[2] = (int)(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
        zoekgetal = new int [1];

        System.out.println("geef 3 verschillende getallen tussen 1 en 8," 
            + " gescheiden door spaties: ");
        zoekgetal[0] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getal));

        if(komtVoorIn(zoekgetal = getal) == true){

        } else {

        }            
    }        
}
```

either way how can i correct this and convert the int so that the if statement will be correct?
i thank you

Comment: What line do you get the error at?

Comment: I think you need a comma instead of the = on the line ```if(komtVoorIn(zoekgetal = getal) == true){```

Comment: Also, komtVoorIn takes an integer for its first argument, and you're passing ```zoekgetal```, which is an integer array. You need to pass ```zoekgetal[0]``` or ```zoekgetal[i]``` where i is a loop variable looping over its contents.

Comment: i get the error at the if statement, how can i use the if statement that zoekgetal has to be the same as getal to print something,

Comment: ```zoekgetal has to be the same as getal``` --> You mean that if all elements in both arrays are equal, you want the if statement to be true?

Comment: yeah, but i cant do that  because it tells me: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int

Comment: To compare 2 arrays, use ```Arrays.equals(zoekgetal,getal)``` It returns ```true``` if they're equal. You can't use == to compare arrays, because that will compare their ```references```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
public class NewChanceOefententamen {

    public static boolean komtVoorIn(int zoekgetal, int[] lijst) { // de methode
                                                                // die
                                                                // checkt of
                                                                // het getal
                                                                // voorkomt
        for (int i = 0; i < lijst.length; i++) { // voor elk getal in het array
            if (zoekgetal == lijst[i]) { // als het overeenkomt met de waarde in
                                        // het array
                return true; // return true
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] zoekgetal = new int[3];
        int[] getal = new int[3];
        getal = new int[3];
        getal[0] = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 1);
        getal[1] = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 1);
        getal[2] = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 1);
        zoekgetal = new int[1];

        System.out.println("geef 3 verschillende getallen tussen 1 en 8, gescheiden door spaties: ");
        zoekgetal[0] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getal));

        if (komtVoorIn(zoekgetal[0], getal) == true) {
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the komVoorin function with incorrect arguments

Comment: and how can i use it with correct arguments, can u give an example ?